# Want to get the matching Date & time from values in a file which match with the server current Date and time using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, timestamp, datetimerangefield

I am a beginner in scripting and I am trying  to set TPS value for a system according to the time of the server when it executes the script. I am having csv file which contains start time , End time and TPS columns which starts from 00:00 to 23:59 as follows.

```
StartTime,EndTime,TPS
.....,.....,...
.....,.....,...
11:30,12:00,100
12:00,12:45,200
12:45,13:30,520
.....,.....,...
.....,.....,...
23:40,23:50,920
23:50,23:59,250
```

Time gaps are not uniform.
if the server current time is 11:35, I want to chose the "11:30,12:00,100" line and get it into a seperate file (since 11:35 lies between 11:30-12:00). Also the chosen line will be deleted from the initial csv file.

```
#Current time into a variable
TS=$(date | cut -d ' ' -f4 | cut -d ':' -f1,2)
echo "Current time = $TS"
```

Writing the relevant line to a seperate file and removing that line from the initial file is fine for me.

if the TS=11:35, I want to get the output as "11:30,12:00,100" from that csv file.
Struggling to code how to get that matching line.

Comment: Question is not really clear for me. What's TPS? What's the expected output of the snippet?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service; you're expected to show your (coding) effort, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output, making sure both sets of output correspond to the provided sample input

Comment: TPS means Transactions per second. Just ignore it. I want to get a matching range from the csv file to a given specific time ( server time "$date"). That's only .

Comment: please confirm that if the current time is `12:00` then you want to print both lines `11:30,12:00,100` and `12:00,12:45,200` as well as remove both lines (from the csv)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Your "datalist" seem improperly conceived for full coverage.  You have gaps of 1 minute at each interval which is not being captured.

To get proper coverage of all activity, you need to have first time period ending with **${EndTime_1}** ... and ... the next time period starting with **${StrtTime_2}**=${EndTime_1}.

When scanning, you should specify range as

```
if [ "${StrtTime_x}" -le "${LineTime}" -a "${LineTime}" -lt "${EndTime_x}" ]
then
    ...{action}...
fi
```

**Note:** the first comparison is **-le** , but the second is only **-lt** , thereby ensuring lines never match both conditions.